# How to convert a file to a byte array in Mule ESB?

Tags: java, image-processing, mule, mule-studio

I'm POSTing a png file to an HTTP inbound endpoint in Mule.  I want to process the file using Java and store the altered image in a database.  Do I need to transform the image in to another format explicitly (e.g. in to a byte array using a Java object), or is there a more streamlined method in Mule to pass the image to my Java bean for processing?  Mule code examples would be helpful.

--- update ---

Based on Chad's response below, is this the way to handle it?  I'm not sure how the code would look to pass it to my Java bean though.

```
<flow name="flow1" doc:name="flow1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <object-to-byte-array-transformer doc:name="Object to Byte Array"/>
    <???>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your payload, I believe, will be an InputStream so you will probably want to perform an <object-to-byte-array-transformer/> to get the byte[] (if that is what you need).

However, depending on your use cases, this could become a memory problem. If I'm dealing with a lot of 500MB images, then getting all of those in memory might cause issues :)

So dumping these out to files and working off of files might be another possibility.

---

Update: It would be different between a Component and a Transformer, but this is an example:

```
<flow name="flow1">
  <http:inbound-endpoint host="localhost" port="8081"/>
  <object-to-byte-array-transformer doc:name="Object to Byte Array"/>
  <component>
    <singleton-object class="com.my.CustomComponent"/>
  </component>
</flow>
```

Then a class would be something like:

```
public class CustomComponent implements Callable {
  public Object onCall(MuleEventContext eventContext) throws Exception {
    //Get at the payload by eventContext.getMessage().getPayload()
    return eventContext.getMessage();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Chad and thank-you.  I updated my question with what you are proposing.  Is the example accurate to your suggestion?  What does the code look like to pass it to my Java bean?  Is it something like <myBean:process/> then in code "public void process(@Payload byteArrayImage)"?